# JavaScript function is not working unless I write alert in the function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsf

I have a jQuery onload function in a JS file. The code is as shown below

```
$(window).load(function() {

  if (($("#dashboardFormId\\:oneMenu1 option:selected").text() === 'Never') ||
    ($("#dashboardFormId\\:oneMenu1 option:selected").text() == 'Default')) {
    $('#dashboardFormId\\:secsDropdown').hide();
  }
});
```

The above is code is not hiding the `secsDropdown`. The below code having `alert()` inside the `if` block is working as expected.

```
$(window).load(function() {

  if (($("#dashboardFormId\\:oneMenu1 option:selected").text() === 'Never') ||
    ($("#dashboardFormId\\:oneMenu1 option:selected").text() == 'Default')) {
    alert()
    $('#dashboardFormId\\:secsDropdown').hide();
  }
});
```

I have the above code in a separate JS file and I included this script in my XHTML page.

Comment: Is `'#dashboardFormId\\:secsDropdown'` dynamically created? What's `$('#dashboardFormId\\:secsDropdown').length` in both cases?

Comment: The only way I can see the `alert()` making a difference is if the `'#dashboardFormId:secsDropdown` element is dynamically loaded in to the DOM and you aren't waiting for the request that loads it to complete properly.

Comment: This test gets called before any user gets a chance to select any value. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes. Before the user selects the dropdown, I need to check if the existing value of dropdown is "Never". If so, then disable the next dropdown.